# Cannot save all the data into excel spreadsheet using Excel Macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm not that good with Excel Macro

What I'm able to achieve at this point is to recursively searching all the subfolders in the directory I specify and grab all the excel spreadsheet that contains "Issues.xls*" after that I copy the information in the excel spreadsheet and combine all in a Master Excel SpreadSheet. All the Issues.xlsx have 17 columns and unknown row number. I can do all this if I put the button that trigger the macro in the same sheet as I combine the information.

What I cannot do is to put the button in another sheet called "Control Panel" and the put all the combine information in another sheet called "Master Issues". If I do this I can only get partial information in the "Master Issues" and not the full data.

I can only get one excel spreadsheet per subfolders. For example if I have 3 issues, the program will only get the data from one of the excel sheet and not all 3 issues. I know I must make some stupid mistake in the code but I cannot see where I did it wrong.

I would appreciate if you can help me. Thank you very much!!

** Below are my code

Thank you for your help.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FileListingAllFolder()

Dim pPath As String
Dim FlNm As Variant
Dim ListFNm As New Collection ' create a collection of filenames

Dim ShtCnt As Integer
Dim Sht As Integer

Dim LR As Long, NR As Long
Dim wbkOld As Workbook, wbkNew As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

' Open folder selection
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        pPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' Create master workbook with single sheets
    Set wbkNew = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wbkNew.Sheets("Master Issues") 'sheet report is built into...edit to match

    If MsgBox("Import new data to this report?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    If MsgBox("Clear the old data first?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        ws.Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.ClearContents
        NR = 2
    Else
        NR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If


    ' Filling a collection of filenames (search Excel files including subdirectories)
    ' Call FlSrch(ListFNm, pPath, "*.xls", True)
    Call FlSrch(ListFNm, pPath, "Issues.xls*", True)


    ' Print list to immediate debug window and as a message window
    For Each FlNm In ListFNm ' cycle for list(collection) processing
        'Do While Len(FlNm) > 0
        'Open file
            Set wbkOld = Workbooks.Open(FlNm)
        'Find last row and copy data
            Sheets(1).Activate 'Sheets(1).Activate
            LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   'find the bottom row of data...change to a different column if "A" isn't reliable for spotting this value
            Range("A2:A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy _
                ws.Range("A" & NR)
        'close file
            wbkOld.Close False
        'Next row
            NR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'move file to "imported" folder
            'Name fPath & fName As fPathDone & fName         'optional
        'ready next filename
            'FlNm = Dir
        'Loop
    Next FlNm

    ' Print to immediate debug window and message if no file was found
    If ListFNm.Count = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No file was found !"
        MsgBox "No file was found !"
        End
    End If

    Cells.Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

    End

NextCode:
    MsgBox "You Click Cancel, and no folder selected!"

End Sub

Private Sub FlSrch(pFnd As Collection, pPath As String, pMask As String, pSbDir As Boolean)

Dim flDir As String
Dim CldItm As Variant
Dim sCldItm As New Collection

' Add backslash at the end of path if not present
pPath = Trim(pPath)

If Right(pPath, 1) <> "\" Then pPath = pPath & "\"

' Searching files accordant with mask
flDir = Dir(pPath & pMask)
    Do While flDir <> ""
        pFnd.Add pPath & flDir 'add file name to list(collection)
        flDir = Dir ' next file
    Loop

' Procedure exiting if searching in subdirectories isn't enabled
If Not pSbDir Then Exit Sub

' Searching for subdirectories in path
flDir = Dir(pPath & "*", vbDirectory)
    Do While flDir <> ""
    ' Do not search Scheduling folder
        If flDir <> "Scheduling" Then
            ' Add subdirectory to local list(collection) of subdirectories in path
            If flDir <> "." And flDir <> ".." Then If ((GetAttr(pPath & flDir) And _
            vbDirectory) = 16) Then sCldItm.Add pPath & flDir
        End If
        flDir = Dir 'next file
    Loop

' Subdirectories list(collection) processing
For Each CldItm In sCldItm
    Call FlSrch(pFnd, CStr(CldItm), pMask, pSbDir) ' Recursive procedure call
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should prefix all your references with the appropriate book/sheet !  E.g.:

```
'Find last row and copy data
wbkOld.Sheets(1).Activate 'Sheets(1).Activate
LR = wbkOld.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

If you don't do that, you take the risk of referencing the Activesheet of the ActiveWorkbook, whatever that is. You could also rephrase the code above using `With`, this way:

```
'Find last row and copy data
With wbkOld
    .Sheets(1).Activate 'Sheets(1).Activate
    LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to put your code in my program I got "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"